# Chart containing date comparisons using Excel 2013

Tags: excel-2013, excel-charts

I am trying to compare data from November 2017 to November 2018, December 2017 to December 2017 to December 2018 and January 2018 to January 2019 for 5 classes in the same

Column A is titled Classes and has the 5 different classes listed from rows 2-6

Column B has November 2017 and the rows contain percentages

Column C is titled December 2017

Column D is titled January 2018

Column E is titled November 2018

Column F is titled December 2018

and Column G is titled January 2019

I wanted to create a bar chart that would contain have each class and show the data such as November 2017 and November 2018 next to each other.

I tried to change the Horizonal Axis but it doesn't let me change the order in which the dates appear on the chart.

The only way that I have been able to get the desired results so far is to use a pivot chart.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, I have understood the question correctly!!

You can "Switch rows to the column" to "group bar chart on class". When you create a bar chart by selecting the data, right click chart, select "Select Data", Select "Switch row/column", Press Ok.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWjd7.png

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't that clear.  I would like the November 2017 data to be next to the November 2018 data.  I don't know if a line chart would be better....showing Nov, Dec 17 and Jan 18 on one line and Nov, Dec 18 and Jan 19 on another line.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try this:

### Change the plotting order of data series in a chart

Click the chart for which you want to change the plotting order of data series. This displays the Chart Tools.

Under Chart Tools, on the Design tab, in the Data group, click **Select Data**.

In the Select Data Source dialog box, in the Legend Entries (Series) box, click the data series that you want to change the order of.

Click the Move Up or Move Down arrows to move the data series to the position that you want.

*Source: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/change-the-plotting-order-of-categories-values-or-data-series-94108634-ddb1-409a-9a4d-13f57e6e6df5*